# How to split phone numbers in string with spaces use php

Tags: php, regex

I have different strings, contains phone numbers like this:

```
New order to car wash #663. Customer number is 7962555443. Thank you.
```

or

```
New order to car wash #663. Customer number is 50414. Thank you, bye.
```

or

```
New order to car wash #663. A phone number to connect with the customer is 905488739038.
```

I need this:

```
New order to car wash #663. Customer number is 7 9 6 2 5 5 5 4 4 3. Thank you.
```

or

```
New order to car wash #663. Customer number is 5 0 4 1 4. Thank you, bye.
```

or

```
New order to car wash #663. A phone number to connect with the customer is 9 0 5 4 8 8 7 3 9 0 3 8.
```

I need to separate numbers contains more than 3 symbols.

Comment: Show what have you tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a callback for this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\b\d{4,}~', 
     function($m) {
        return implode(' ', str_split($m[0]));
     }, $str);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/414536)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace` alone without any callback function would be sufficient.

```
preg_replace('~#\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\d)(?=\d)~', ' ', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fI0hV3/2)

- `#\d+(*SKIP)(*F)` Matches and discards all the numbers which starts with `#`.
- `|` OR
- `(?<=\d)(?=\d)` Now from the remaining string, this would match the boundary which exists between two digits.
- Now by replacing the matched boundary with space will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Also can do this by using the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Replace with matched digit + space: `"$0 "`

> I need to separate numbers contains more than 3 symbols.

```
$str = preg_replace('~\b\d(?=\d{3})|\G\d\B~', "$0 ", $str);
```

- `\b\d` matches a [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` followed by a digit (`\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[0-9]`)
- `(?=\d{3})` Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check next 3 after first `\d` are digits too
- `|\G\d\B` OR match a digit at `\G` *end of previous match* followed by `\B` *non word-boundary*

See test at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/sH9vD2/3) or [eval.in](https://eval.in/414618)

---

As an alternative could also replace first digit after a `\h` *horizontal space*: [\h\d|\G\d\B](https://www.regex101.com/r/qS1lS2/1)

Comment: Thank you! Your code helped me a lot to improve my regex skill. Tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$phonenumber="7962555443";
$formatted = implode(' ',str_split($phonenumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use implode you just need to use `str_split` first which converts the string to an array:

```
$number="905488739038";    
$formatted = implode(' ',str_split($number));

echo $formatted;
```

Output:

```
9 0 5 4 8 8 7 3 9 0 3 8
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex as well:

```
((?:(?:\d)\s?){4,})
```

It will capture all the number having length four or more. Also you need to do an additional step to remove spaces from the matches from the results like this:

```
7 9 6 2 5 5 5 4 4 3
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/rdHpf5fgbg)